# Complex Analysis (Basic): Simplify this modulus.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have:

$$\left\lvert\frac{(\pi+1)^{100}}{(\pi-1)^{100}}\right\rvert$$

I just need to simplify this, but I can't seem to figure it out right now.

Thanks!

(If someone could tell me the latex for absoulte values, that'd be great).

Comment: I kept your `\lvert` and `\rvert` and merely prefixed them with `\left` and `\right`, respectively, to get them to size automatically.

Comment: I usually use the | key (although \mid is also a vertical bar) . To make them as tall as the object between absolute value bars, use the \left and \right commands before whatever symbol you use.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks guys!

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{(\pi+1)^{100}}{(\pi-1)^{100}}\right|
=
\left|\left(\frac{\pi+1}{\pi-1}\right)^{100}\right|
=
\left(\frac{\pi+1}{\pi-1}\right)^{100}
=
\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi-1}\right)^{100}
$$

Comment: So you actually did the division? More involved than I thought it would be.

Well, cool! Thanks.  Do you mind taking a crack at my additional problem?